# How to get sorted data from array in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to get data in sorted format.Here is my array

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 47
                [user_id] => 2
                [title] => SSS
                [category_id] => 4
                [description] => sss description sss description sss description sss description sss description sss description sss description sss description sss description sss description
                [deliverable_status] => pending reviews
                [created_at] => 2018-01-17 13:26:19
                [updated_at] => 2018-01-17 13:26:19
                [category_name] => Designs
                [reviewer_user_id] => 3
                [email] => def@yopmail.com
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 47
                [user_id] => 2
                [title] => SSS
                [category_id] => 4
                [description] => sss description sss description sss description sss description sss description sss description sss description sss description sss description sss description
                [deliverable_status] => pending reviews
                [created_at] => 2018-01-17 13:26:19
                [updated_at] => 2018-01-17 13:26:19
                [category_name] => Designs
                [reviewer_user_id] => 4
                [email] => abc@yopmail.com
            )

    )
```

)

This two records having same data except reviewer id and email.So i need single array with two email.I need those in single array.Here is the sample array that i need

```
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 47
                [user_id] => 2
                [title] => SSS
                [category_id] => 4
                [description] => sss description sss description sss description sss description sss description sss description sss description sss description sss description sss description
                [deliverable_status] => pending reviews
                [created_at] => 2018-01-17 13:26:19
                [updated_at] => 2018-01-17 13:26:19
                [category_name] => Designs
                [email] => [0] => stdClass Object (
                                       [0] => 'def@yopmail.com',
                                       [1] => 'abc@yopmail.com',
                                  )             
           )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
$result = $collection->unique('id')
    ->map(function ($item) use ($collection) {
        $item->email = $collection->where('id', $item->id)
            ->pluck('email')
            ->toArray();
        return $item;
    })
    ->first();
```

Result will be:

```
stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 47
                [user_id] => 2
                [title] => SSS
                [category_id] => 4
                [description] => sss description sss description sss description sss description sss description sss description sss description sss description sss description sss description
                [deliverable_status] => pending reviews
                [created_at] => 2018-01-17 13:26:19
                [updated_at] => 2018-01-17 13:26:19
                [category_name] => Designs
                [email] => Array (
                                       [0] => 'def@yopmail.com',
                                       [1] => 'abc@yopmail.com',
                                  )             
           )
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try:**

```
$sortedarray = array_unique(array_merge($items[0],$items[1]), SORT_REGULAR);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting data from Database you can try that in your query in select method

```
DB::raw('group_concat(colum_name) as names')
```